# How to use Android Layout and custom GUI design in this

Tags: android, xml, facebook, android-layout, user-interface

I'm trying to make customized design and style of widgets in my android app. So can anyone suggest me code how to make this kind of GUI in android using xml or any other code. 
Curves in text fields, button styles, lines, checkbox style, rounded facebook button, line between ----OR----- .....

Comment: see this site please, that very good for create custom shape for Button , http://angrytools.com/android/button/

Comment: I'd take a look at 9-patch for the TextField backgrounds. This seems like an exercise in asset design.

Comment: @Shyan pourvatan Thank you for this link and what about checkbox and text fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I create this for you with [this link](http://angrytools.com/android/button/)

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/email_shape"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:inputType="text" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@drawable/password_shape"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
    android:hint="Password" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
    android:background="@drawable/go_shape"
    android:text="Go" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:background="#ccc" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:background="#ccc" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="forgot password ?"
    android:textColor="#555"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="remember me"
    android:textColor="#555" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="New User Click to"
    android:textColor="#555" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Sign Up !"
    android:textColor="#F2272D"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView8"
    android:background="#ccc"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="or" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#ccc"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
    android:background="@drawable/facebook_shape"
    android:text="facebook" />
```

email_shape:

```
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

<solid android:color="#F2F2F2" />


<size
    android:height="60dp"
    android:width="270dp" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#878787" />
```

password_shape:

```
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

<solid android:color="#F2F2F2" />

<size
    android:height="60dp"
    android:width="270dp" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#878787" />
```

facebook_shape:

```
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="50dp"
    android:topRightRadius="50dp" />

<solid android:color="#3F45F2" />

<size
    android:height="60dp"
    android:width="270dp" />
```

go_shape:

```
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

<solid android:color="#F2272D" />

<size
    android:height="60dp"
    android:width="270dp" />
```

create all *_shape.xml in `drawable` folder in `res`

for remember me you can create two image and change that

and result is

[image]

I hope this can help you

Comment: Thank you for the code. And can you also tell me for checkbox ?